# Dart - how to convert Map<String, dynamic> to Map<String, String>

Tags: dart

This snippet compile successfully but fail in runtime

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters = {"id": 3};
Map<String, String> stringQueryParameters = Map<String, String>.from(queryParameters);
```

> Uncaught Error: TypeError: 3: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'

---

**What's the proper way to convert from `Map<String, dynamic>` to `Map<String, String>` ?**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use `.map` to convert your keys:

```dart
  Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters = {"id": 3};
  Map<String, String> stringQueryParameters =
      queryParameters.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value?.toString()));
```

Comment: Map<String, String> mapResult = queryParameters.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value != null ? value!.toString() : ''));

Answer (score 4):

Loop all items, call `.toString()` and store the result as the new value

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters = {"id": 3, "name": null};
Map<String, String> stringQueryParameters = Map<String, String>();
queryParameters.forEach((key, value) => stringQueryParameters[key] = value?.toString());

// ...
```