# How to properly add request fields to a Dart MultipartRequest

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app in which I normally use http request post from a model to a go API like this.

```
if (dateRequired != null) {
  data['date_required'] = dateRequired?.formatDbDate();
} else {
  data['date_required'] = null;
}
```

However, I want to upload files and decode json data at the same time. The upload file as below works but the result I get from the code below produces either `(2023-11-12)`
or `(null)` which throws a decode error in my api. I was expecting `{"date_required": null}` or `{"date_required": 2023-11-12}`.

How can I get to that? I notice that dart http uses `Map<String, dynamic>` while dart `MultipartRequest` uses `Map<String, String>` so I can use null. This will require further parsing in my go api.

```
Future<dynamic> uploadFile(
      BuildContext context, User user, String dateRequiredString) async {
    final navigator = Navigator.of(context);

    const storage = FlutterSecureStorage();

    String? token = await storage.read(key: 'jwt');

    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
    };

    final bytes = file?.bytes;

    if (file == null || bytes == null) return;

    final multipartFile =
        http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('file', bytes, filename: file?.name);

    final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(user.fileUrl));

    request.files.add(multipartFile);

    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    request.fields['date_required'] = dateRequiredString;
```

Dart code to produce the field, edited to in accordance with the answer from @mandy8055.

```
                                if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                  if (_formKey
                                          .currentState
                                          ?.fields['date_required']
                                          ?.value !=
                                      null) {
                                    dateRequired = _formKey.currentState
                                        ?.fields['date_required']!.value;
                                  }

                                  Map<String, dynamic> data = {
                                    'date_required': dateRequired != null
                                        ? dateRequired!.formatDbDate()
                                        : null
                                  };

                                  print(data);

                                  Map<String, String> dateRequiredString =
                                      jsonEncode(data)
                                          as Map<String, String>;

                                  print(dateRequiredString);
```

This produces the following console output

```
{date_required: null}
Error: Expected a value of type 'Map<String, String>', but got one of type 'String'
```

further edit:

```
                            _formKey.currentState?.save();

                            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                              if (_formKey
                                      .currentState
                                      ?.fields['date_required']
                                      ?.value !=
                                  null) {
                                dateRequired = _formKey.currentState
                                    ?.fields['date_required']!.value;
                              }

                              Map<String, dynamic> data = {
                                'date_required': dateRequired != null
                                    ? dateRequired!.formatDbDate()
                                    : null
                              };

                              String jsonString = jsonEncode(data);

                              Map<String, dynamic> decodedMap =
                                  jsonDecode(jsonString);

                              Map<String, String> dateRequiredString =
                                  decodedMap.cast<String, String>();

                              print(data);

                              print(dateRequiredString);

                              uploadFile(
                                  context, user, dateRequiredString);
                            }
```

this throws the error below (the date is meant to be null here). I see the key is not quoted but I think it should be quoted.

```
{date_required: null}
Error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'
```

Here is some working code to demonstrate the issue. I need to convert the `Map<String, dynamic>` to `Map<String, String>` and retain the quotes around the "date_required" key.

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = {'date_required': null};

  print(data);

  String jsonString = jsonEncode(data);

  print(jsonString);

  Map<String, dynamic> decodedMap = jsonDecode(jsonString);

  print(decodedMap);

  Map<String, String> dateRequiredString = decodedMap.cast<String, String>();

  print(dateRequiredString);
}
```

Console output:

```
{date_required: null}
{"date_required":null}
{date_required: null}
: TypeError: null: type 'JSNull' is not a subtype of type 'String'Error: TypeError: null: type 'JSNull' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

Comment: it would require a lot of code I imagine. The crux of the problem is just assigning request fields correctly.

Comment: Dart `null.toString()` returns `"null"`. I can't just pass null as explained above.

Comment: Your solution works. Please write this up as an anser but the result is `({"date_required":null})` which the api doesn't like, presumably because of an extra bracket.

Comment: From your new edit remove `as Map<String, String>;`, so it will become `String dateRequiredString = jsonEncode(data)`

Comment: It would be nice to share your code on Dartpad or git so it can be reviewed properly.

other than that, what about fields['date_required'] ?? DateFormat('yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm').format(DateTime.now())

this way you don't have to deal with null and your value is always a string.

Comment: What do I do when I want a null date?

Comment: hmmm, maybe you can ignore the initialization of the field altogether and handle the absence of it directly in your backend? so

if(_formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
 if(your_value != null) {
   request.fields['date_required'] = your_value;
  }
}

that way date_required will only be created if it has a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to correctly transform and map the data types between Dart's `Map<String, dynamic>` and `Map<String, String>` (a bit as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61975389/6309)).
You want to:

- send nullable data (`date_required`) along with file upload.
- maintain compatibility between `Map<String, dynamic>` and `Map<String, String>`.

Try and convert nullable `date_required` to a string representation. Then, make sure `null` values are handled correctly.

```dart
Future<dynamic> uploadFile(BuildContext context, User user, String? dateRequired) async {
    // existing setup code

    // Convert nullable date to a string representation
    String dateRequiredStr = dateRequired != null ? jsonEncode({'date_required': dateRequired}) : jsonEncode({'date_required': null});

    // Adding fields to the request
    request.fields['data'] = dateRequiredStr;

    // remaining code for file upload
}
```

Use [`jsonEncode`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html) to convert the `Map<String, dynamic>` to a `String`. Assign this JSON string directly to a field in `request.fields`.

---

For the Go API, you will need to parse the 'data' field as a JSON string and handle it accordingly.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = {'date_required': null};

  String jsonString = jsonEncode(data); // Convert map to JSON string

  print(jsonString); // {"date_required":null}

  // Directly use jsonString in your request.fields
  // Example: request.fields['data'] = jsonString;
}

// Note: There is no need to convert back to Map<String, String> in Dart.
// Handle the JSON parsing in your Go API.
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the conversion of `date_required` value to a string using `.toString()` function. The fix for this would be to use JSON encoding for the `date_required` field, which will properly handle the `null` value. You can use the ***[`dart:convert`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html)*** library for the fix.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
// Rest of code
String dateRequiredString = json.encode({
  'date_required': dateRequired != null
      ? dateRequired!.formatDbDate()
      : null
});
// ...rest of code
request.fields.addAll(json.decode(dateRequiredString) as Map<String, String>);
                        // ^^^^^^ Do not forget to decode if there is any need to get back the Map.
```

**EDIT:**

I am not aware about your full code requirement. But I'll try to provide the hint to get rid of the error which you posted in the comment. As per the **[docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html)**, jsonEncode returns `string` and not `Map`. The problem will be resolved by typecasting decoded string to `Map`. A small sample snippet would be like:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = {'date_required': null};
  
  String jsonString = jsonEncode(data);
  Map<String, dynamic> decodedMap = jsonDecode(jsonString);
  Map<String, String> dateRequiredString = decodedMap.cast<String, String>(); // <--- Notice this.
  
  print(dateRequiredString);
}
```

Comment: ` Map<String, String> dateRequiredString =   jsonEncode(data)  as Map<String, String>;` throws `{date_required: null}`
`Error: Expected a value of type 'Map<String, String>', but got one of type 'String'`

Comment: I have no idea how to fix that

Comment: Is it not equivalent? It seems cleaner to do it before calling the function.

Comment: The code you suggested throws an error at `print(dateRequiredString);` I have edited my question to reflect the actual code I used.

Comment: @markhorrocks, I think I have got your point. Just to reconfirm if ***[this](https://dartpad.dev/?id=2c97e27a9dfbc15618e44c83414ffca8)*** helps; then I'll update my answer

Comment: I believe the final product needs to have the key quoted and should look like this `{"date_required":null}` only be a `Map<String, String>` or my go API json decode function will have a tizzy. Please advise me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @markhorrocks Let's give it a thought from the starting point of your problem. You encode the json using `jsonEncode()`. The data gets converted to `String`. Now, what if you send the data to API without decoding it to GO API? Is it giving some issues. Like only encode the json(whose type is String) and send it. Are you getting some error doing so?

Comment: Not as yet. I can't test this until tomorrow SEA time. It does look like the go decoder won't like it. Dart from a model formats nicely.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a solution to the issue of uploading a file and form data at the same time, I found the method of using a mutipart reader in my go API to be very complex and could not make it work. Moreover, that approach loses the file size, necessitating pushing the file size in the header using content disposition.

At that point I determined that it was simply easier to only upload the file in the Multipart form and to put the date required into the content disposition header. This solution was easy to implement and works very well.